# Newsstand free subscription and Apple hosted content

Tags: ios, app-store, storekit, newsstand-kit

I am currently working on a Newsstand app and plan on releasing it soon.
My magazine issues are currently hosted on Apple servers via Non-consumable In-App purchase products. I understood that in order to pass the Apple Store validation I need to set up a free or auto-renewable subscription product.
My concern is, how can I link this free subscription to the IAP products? I realise I can't download these issues vie the StoreKit APi without purchasing them individually, making any form of subscription useless?